# Detecting handwritten lines using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, handwriting

I'm trying to detect underlines and boxes in the following image:

[image]

For example, this is the output I'm aiming for:

[image]

Here's what I've atempted:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('document.jpg')

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)

# Apply Canny Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 155, 200)

# Use HoughLinesP to detect lines
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=1*np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=50)

# Draw lines on image
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 4)
```

However, this is the result I get:

[image]

Here are my thoughts regarding this problem:

1. I might need to use adaptive thresholding with Otsu's algorithm to provide a proper binary image to `cv2.Canny()`. However, I doubt this is the core issue. Here is how the image looks with the current thresholding applied:

[image]

`cv2.threshold()` already does a decent job separating the notes from the page.

2. Once I get `HoughLinesP()` to properly draw all the lines (and not the weird scribbles it's currently outputting), I can write some sort of box detector function to find the boxes based on the intersections (or near-intersections) of four lines. As for underlines, I simply need to detect horizontal lines from the output of `HoughLinesP()`, which shouldn't be difficult (e.g., for any given line, check if the two y coordinates are within some range of each other).

**So the fundamental problem I have is this: how do I get `HoughLinesP()` to output smoother lines and not the current mess it's giving so I can then move forward with detecting boxes and lines?**

Additionally, do my proposed methods for finding boxes and underlines make sense from an efficiency standpoint? Does OpenCV provide a better way for achieving what I want to accomplish?

Comment: Canny edges is not a good idea. It will extract lines from the lines in the paper. You need to remove the paper lines first and also the whiten the background color. You can do the latter with division normalization (divide the image by its blurred version).  But I am not sure at the moment how you will remove the lines from the paper. Do you have a clean template image of just the paper without writing that could be aligned and subtracted?

Comment: @fmw42 I do have a clean template image! How would I go about subtracting it from the scanned image?

Comment: Find a crossing points of the lines near each corners of each image. Then find the homography and do a perspective warp to align the two images. Then subtract. Search google for examples of finding the homography and doing a perspective warp.